# Weird behavior in Django

Tags: python, django, url

we have interest and add_interest just like we did in the range app but with everything similar to range app and the correct url shown, the add_interest returns an interest page instead of the add_interest page and raise Interest matching query does not exist error.  Where it should in the interest view, we just cannot figure out what is going on and continue please help us
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/Users/a123/Desktop/matemaker_project/matemaker/views.py in interest
    interest = interests.get(slug=interest_name)    # search through genre interests for specified interest.  …
▶ Local vars
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get
            raise self.model.DoesNotExist( …
▶ Local vars
```

## view for individual interest pages

```
def interest(request, genre_name, interest_name):
    context_dict = {}
    genre = Genre.objects.get(slug=genre_name)
    interests = Interest.objects.filter(genre=genre)   # get interests related to genre
    interest = interests.get(slug=interest_name)    # search through genre interests for specified interest. 

    context_dict['genre'] = genre
    context_dict['interest'] = interest
    context_dict['genre_slug'] = genre.slug
    context_dict['interest_slug'] = interest.slug
    response = render(request, 'matemaker/intrest.html', context = context_dict)
    visitor_cookie_handler(request,response,Interest)

    return response

@login_required
def add_interest(request, genre_name):
    try:
        genre = Genre.objects.get(slug=genre_name)
    except Genre.DoesNotExist:
        genre = None
    if genre is None:
        return redirect('/matemaker/genres/')
    
    form = InterestForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InterestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if genre:
                interest = form.save(commit=False)
                interest.genre = genre
                interest.creator = request.user
                interest.date = timezone.now()
                interest.members = int(interest.members)+1
                interest.save()
                return redirect(reverse('matemaker:genre',  kwargs={'genre_name' : genre_name}))

        else: 
            print(form.errors)
    context_dict = {'form': form, 'genre': genre}
    return render(request, 'matemaker/createintrestpage.html', context_dict)
```

In urls.py:

```
path('genres/<slug:genre_name>/<slug:interest_name>/', views.interest, name='interest’),
path('genres/<slug:genre_name>/add_interest/', views.add_interest, name='add_interest'),
```

Comment: The url pattern `genres/<slug:genre_name>/<slug:interest_name>/` matches `genres/<slug:genre_name>/add_interest/`. Hence the view `views.interest` would be used regardless as it is the first in order. (In simple words: `add_interest` can be an interest name)

Comment: wow that helps me so much thank man for quick and nice answer